# Changing the log message in log4j log message with no change in pattern

Tags: logging, log4j, slf4j, rollingfileappender

Currently we are using Log4j with slf4j and maven. We use the pattern layout with daily rolling apprender.

Everything is configured properly and working fine.

Its a client - server module. We need to make some changes in the server logs.

We get logger instances in the classes as

```
private static Logger logger 
    = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyServer.class);
```

Since its a server, we generate our own unique request id and it is part of the MDC.

Now, when we log messages, it might contain logs with multiple lines, eg:

```
 [REQ-1] log line 1
 log line 2
```

How do i make it come as

```
 [REQ] log line 1 {remove new line and put some ascii character} log line 2 ....
```

So, when I grep for REQ-1, i get both the lines and not only 'log line 1' as in the first case

I would want to remove the new line in the log message and replace it with my own ascii character and replace it back with new line when I want to read the logs

Any points would be of great help

Thanks

Comment: Can you change the log4j configuration file?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Sure, I can change the log4j configuration